# Rule 2.3 MISRA A project should not contain unused type declarations

Tags: c, misra

Whats means for "project"?

And in follow statement

"If a type is declared but not used, then it is unclear to a reviewer if the type is redundant or it has been left unused by mistake."

Whats mean "if type is redundant"? What is a redundant type?

Comment: I think you could rephrase it as "it's unclear to the reviewer whether the type is truly not needed, or whether it should have been used but the programmer forgot." So "redundant" isn't a mechanically checkable concept here, it has to do with intent/goals, i.e. whether the type *should* have been used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MISRA document does not contain a strict definition of the "project". Intuitively, a project can be defined as a collection of source files used to build a set of artifacts.

Redundant type in this context means a type definition that is not used in the project sources. They can be easily detected using `-Wunused-local-typedefs` option in the recent versions of gcc and clang.

Answer (score 1):

This is a family of rules from under MISRA-C:2012 2.x that in plain English say that you should never declare any variables, types, macros etc that aren't actually used anywhere in the program. Which is common sense - redundant simply means not used anywhere.

But note that these rules are mainly there for the benefit of the static analyser - this is the kind of checks that you definitely wish to automate. For mission-critical systems in general, we aren't allow to have parts of the production code which are never actually executed. Not even code which is "commented out" is allowed.